# Binding to WPF DataGrid using Entity Framework. Path with index issue

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, data-binding

I've got trouble binding WPF DataGrid control to a List of Entity Framework's entities: `List<ClassOneObject>`.
First I get it from DB in ViewModel. Navigation properties inluded:

```
var db = new Entities();
var resQuery = db.ClassOneObjects
                .Include("Building.Material")
                .Include("Building.BAStreet.Area.District")
                //...
                .Include("ClassOneSources").Where(x => true);
Results = resQuery.ToList();
```

Then try to bind to Datagrid in XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="Results">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Building.BAStreet.Area.District.DistrictName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Building.Material.MaterialShortName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ClassOneSources[0].URL}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

First two columns bind well. Here `Building` is a Navigation property that references single instance of another entity type etc.

But third column not binds. `ClassOneSources` Navigation property references a **collection** of another type entities (one-to-many relationship in DB). Binding path with index not works in this case. What's wrong here?

**UPDATE:**
Binding error in output window:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '[]' property not found on 'object' ''HashSet`1' (HashCode=33586167)'. BindingExpression:Path=ClassOneSources[0].URL; DataItem='ClassOneObject' (HashCode=17651405); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

I figured out something:

EF returned list of ClassOneSources as `HashSet<ClassOneSource>`
If I cast it to List like this:

```
Results[0].ClassOneSources = Results[0].ClassOneSources.ToList();
```

Then it binds OK (only first item of `Results` collection of course).
So binding to HashSet is not working. Is there any way to make EF generate `Lists` instead `HashSets`?

Database:

[image: Database]

Entity Framework data model:

[image: Entity Framework data model]

Comment: any binding errors in your output window?

Comment: @blindmeis, I've got an error. B.t.w. I didn't know about binding errors in output.  Please take a look on update.